# How many $T_0$ topologies are possible for a set of 3 elements? Count only the non-homeomorphic topologies, and list them for X={a, b, c}

Tags: general-topology

The definition that I am working with for $T_0$ is as follows:

Definition 10: $T_0$: (X, τ) is said to be a $T_0$ space if " x ≠ y in X, either there exists U ∈  such that x ∈ U and y ∈ ~U or there exists V ∈  such that y ∈ V and x ∈ ~V.

My main problem with this was discovering what the non-homeomorphic topologies on X are supposed to be.

Below are what I believe to be the non-homeomorphic topologies on X and why they are or are not $T_0$. These are listed in no particular order, and U and V represent open subsets in their respective topologies as per the definition.

$_1$ = {ø, X}, the trivial topology, which is ***not $T_0$*** for sets with more than 1 element

$_2$ = {ø, {a}, {b}, {c}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}, X}, the discrete topology, ***which is $T_0$***.

$_3$ = {ø, {a}, X}, ***Not $T_0$*** since there is no b ∈ U, c ∈ ~U or C ∈ V, B ∈ ~V.

$_4$ = {ø, {a, b} X}, ***Not $T_0$***, there is no a ∈ U, b ∈ ~U, or b ∈ V, a ∈ ~V.

$_5$ = {ø, {a}, {a, b}, X} ***Not $T_0$***, there is not b ∈ U, C ∈ ~U, or c ∈ V, b ∈ ~V.

$_6$ = {ø, {a}, {b, c}, X} ***Not $T_0$*** for the same reasons as $_5$.

$_7$ = {ø, {a}, {b}, {a, b}, X} ***$T_0$***, there exists a ∈ U, and c, b ∈ ~U, as well as b ∈ V, and a, c ∈ ~V, which is enough to show $T_0$.

$_8$ = {ø, {b}, {a, b}, {b, c}, X} ***Not $T_0$***, there is no a ∈ U, c ∈ ~U, or c ∈ V, a ∈ ~V.

$_9$ = {ø, {a}, {b}, {a, b}, {b, c}, X} ***$T_0$***, there exist a ∈ U, and b, c ∈ ~U as well as b ∈ V, and a, c ∈ ~V which is enough to show $T_0$.

Therefore, there are 3 possible non-homeomorphic topologies on X, $_9$, $_7$, $_2$.

Is my list of non-homeomorphic topologies on X complete? Am I understanding these definitions correctly?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_topological_space#3_points is a useful resource.

Comment: @StevenClontz That certainly solves it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's a list [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_topological_space#3_points) but it has no proof that the constructions are exhaustive.

First I'll prove every finite $T_0$ space must have an isolated point. Suppose not. Then suppose $F$ is an open set with $|F|>1$ minimal. Choose $x,y\in F$. There must be some open $U$ containing exactly one of $x,y$. Then $U\cap F$ is open and $|U\cap F|<|F|$, contradiction.

[Finite topologies are Alexandrov](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000266), which means each finite topology $X$ has a unique basis $\mathcal B=\{U_x:x\in X\}$ where $U_x$ is the minimal open set containing each $x\in X$. So let's focus on how many such non-equivalent bases exist on $\{a,b,c\}$.

So for $\{a,b,c\}$ we may assume $U_a=\{a\}$. One possibility is $U_b=\{b\}$ and $U_c=\{c\}$ (the discrete topology). (Count: 1.)

Another possibility is exactly one of $U_b=\{b\}$ and $U_c=\{c\}$ holds; assume $U_b=\{b\}$. Then either $|U_c|=2$ or $|U_c|=3$. In the first case we have either $U_c=\{a,c\}$ or $U_c=\{b,c\}$; these result in homeomorphic topologies. In the second case we have $U_c=\{a,b,c\}$. (Count: 1+2=3.)

Finally we have both $|U_b|>1$ and $|U_c|>1$. By $T_0$ either $c\not\in U_b$ or $b\not\in U_c$; let's assume the former. Thus $U_b=\{a,b\}$. Finally we have exactly two choices for $U_c$: either $U_c=\{a,b,c\}$ or $U_c=\{a,c\}$. This is because $U_c=\{b,c\}$ leads to the contradiction $U_b\cap U_c=\{b\}\subsetneq U_b$. (Final count: 3+2=5.)